# How to install PIL or Pillow in Ubuntu 22.04?

Tags: software-installation, python, libraries, pip

In Ubuntu 22.04, I discovered that the `Python Image Library` `(PIL)` or `(Pillow)` is preinstalled

```
$ pip3 list -v | grep Pillow
Pillow                  9.0.1           /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages
```

However, its [latest version](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) is 9.4.0 and I want to use that.

Should I do (1) or (2)?

1. ```
   python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
   ```
2. ```
   python3 -m pip install --user Pillow
   ```

If `--upgrade` is used, it will upgrade Pilow. But I am concerned that it will cause conflict with other Ubuntu 22.04 system packages designed to use `Pillow 9.0.1`? (1) was given by [Pillow](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html).

If `--user` is used, I think it should install `Pillow 9.4.0` in my local directory `/home/user/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages`. Hence when I do `import PIL` in any python script, Pillow 9.4.0 should be called as a default.

Which option should I use?

PS. I am aware that there is a third option which is to create a virtual env for the script I am creating and to install Pillow 9.4.0 there. But I do not need to do this for a small script hence not considering this option.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like option 2 won't work given that a Pillow package already exists or is installed. Option 1 is the way.

```
$ python3 -m pip install --user Pillow
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (9.0.1)
$ python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: Pillow in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (9.0.1)
Collecting Pillow
  Downloading Pillow-9.4.0-cp310-cp310-manylinux_2_28_x86_64.whl (3.4 MB)
     ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 3.4/3.4 MB 15.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-9.4.0
```